# problem in showing latitude longitude location in an android app

Tags: android, location

Following is the code which i am using to find the latitude longitude and location of a place in my app, but it always show no location found

I have added the permissions in manifest file

{
  `LocationManager locManager;
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        locManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);`

```
    locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,1000L,500.0f, locationListener);
    Location location = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER); 
    if(location != null)                                
     {
        String param = (String)locManager.getProviders(true).get(0);
        Location loc = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(param);

      double latitude = location.getLatitude();
      double longitude = location.getLongitude();
     }  
}

    private void updateWithNewLocation(Location location) 
    {
            TextView myLocationText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.widget52);
            String latLongString = " ";
            if (location != null) 
            {
                double lat = location.getLatitude();
                double lng = location.getLongitude();
                latLongString = "Lat:" + lat + "\nLong:" + lng;

            } 
            else 
            {
                latLongString = "No location found";
            }
             myLocationText.setText("Your Current Position is:\n" +
                    latLongString);
    }

        private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() 
        {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
            {
                updateWithNewLocation(location);
            }

            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) 
            {
                updateWithNewLocation(null);
            }

            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) 
            {
            }

            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) 
            {
            }
        };
```

}

pls help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've put your code in an Android project and ran it on the emulator and it seems to be working fine.

I would change the code to **first** check for a lastknown location, and **after** that check for location updates.

```
Location location = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

If that location is null, or too stale (timestamp) for your needs, you can start requesting location updates. (currently, you're first requesting location updates from the GPS, and then decide to retrieve its lastknownlocation). This might cause the location manager to stop querying the GPS.

Also you need  to ensure the following is in place :

**For GPS Provider, make sure the following permission is put in the manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

**Ensure the GPS is turned on that you have sufficient GPS coverage.**

Do this by checking for the GPS icon in your Notification bar

**Test on a real device**

Although testing GPS location listeners works partly through the emulator, the behavior of an actual device will always be different.

**Debug on the emulator**

Basic GPS testing can be done using the emulator. Put a breakpoint in your locationlistener, and use the DDMS perspective to send some GPS coordinates to your AVD image.

Answer (score 0):

@Siva, your problem is with the UI thread, as your updates are from different thread.

To verify if this is the UI problem, put a toast or Log cat the message when you receive an update.

Once you know that UI problem, then try using [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to [postInvalidate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postInvalidate%28%29)() the UI.

Comment: Based on the code above, everything is running in the UI thread so that shouldn't be an issue. The location listener onLocationChanged will be executed on the main UI thread here, so updating his TextView should happen providing the location is not null.